# How to format detailed app description

Tags: windows-phone-7

How can we format the detailed app description when submitting an app?

Entering a simple bulleted list like this:

- See multiple currencies
- Conversion for ...

Shows this ugly on the phone Marketplace:

[image: Windows Marketplace Detailed Description]

Comment: Questions about how the marketplace operates should be asked over on [windowsphone.se].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Do Not Use Formatting**

In the S.O. question "[Tips for a successful Windows Phone 7 Marketplace submission](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4141186/9664)", one of the [Answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4141420/9664) states:

> Don't use formatting in your marketplace description as it won't be
>   preserved consistently when displayed in the Marketplace.

The blog post "[Tip 5–Don’t use formatting in your Marketplace Descriptions](http://websurfaces.co.uk/2010/10/14/tip-5dont-use-formatting-in-your-marketplace-descriptions/)" also details that copy/pasting of html fails as well.

**App Hub May Contradict the Above**

However, the "[app hub application submission walkthrough](http://create.msdn.com/en-US/home/about/app_submission_walkthrough)" clearly states under the Detailed Description Checklist (item 5):

> Include bullet points to highlight features of the app. Bullet points
>   should also be brief. Don't have more than six bullet points

So, it seems that there may be the ability to use some type of bullet list in the Detailed Description, yet there are no readily available guidelines on how to correctly format the bullet list.

**Possible Options**

One suggestion would be to use textual bullets, i.e,

```
- See multiple currencies
- Conversion for...
- etc...
```

Finally, as a last resort, submit a support ticket to the marketplace and quote the "app hub application submission walkthrough" I quoted above and ask them where the guidelines are for creating bullet-points.

Comment: Thanks for this complete sum up. Exactly my findings. The simple textual bullets do not work - see screenshot. Continued here: http://forums.create.msdn.com/forums/t/103918.aspx